# What SQL query in sqllite need to calculate with today's timestamp using time in seconds?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, time, timestamp

I have SQLite database table `tasks` (aka tasks in my own project management system). I have columns `start_date` which is timestamp of task's start time in seconds. Then, columns `lifetime` - time to work with task in seconds.

I need to write a SQL query to get tasks which are still open. I need

```
startdate + lifetime < today's timestamp
```

I use 'UNIX-beginning' start time.

It looks like:

```
tasks.start_date  tasks.lifetime  functionToCalculateSecondsFromUnixBirthday
1551528199281 + 8650010 > 1551566849291
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tasks 
WHERE (tasks.start_date + tasks.lifetime) > strftime('%s','now');
```

returns all from tasks in resultset, maybe something with arithmetic syntax?

Table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks`
(
     `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, 
     `name` TEXT, 
     `project_id` INTEGER, 
     `start_date` TEXT, 
     `lifetime` TEXT, 
     `targetinfo` TEXT
);
```

Comment: thank you for formatting

Comment: The query is correct. But idea to compare java Timestamp with SQL strftime('%s','now') was wrong. So sorry for the question.

Comment: What does your table definition look like? (Add, properly formatted as a code block, to your question; don't try to put it in a comment)

Comment: i can not edit the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1551566849291** includes milliseconds, whilst **`strftime('%s','now')`** is only seconds.

That is `strftime('%s','now')` results in **1549308478** so is going to be considerably lower than **1551566849291**.

perhaps use :-

```
SELECT * 
FROM tasks 
WHERE (tasks.start_date + tasks.lifetime) > (strftime('%s','now') * 1000);
```

Comment: @ОстапСтрашевский that's good, could you please tick the answer if you believe that it helped you.